# Grants Management - Submit Application

Tags: community, lightning-experience, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, grants-managment

I have installed the **Grants Managemen**t package, which includes **communitySubmitApplicationButton** component. When I open funding request detail page, where this component has been placed. The component looks like empty, even in builder. I opened page as an admin, so it's unlikely to be related to permissions to run flow.

[image: image from builder here]
[image: properties for component]

Does anyone have the same problem?